# Foreach for complex array

Tags: php, json

I get stuck with that. I have 0 ideas to do that. I have this string in json:

```
$json = json_encode(
array(
    'error'=> 'false',
        'tasks' => array(
            1 => array(
                'id' => 4,
                'task' => 'Prueba'
            ),
            2 => array(
                'id' => 9,
                'task' => 'Psdasdrueba'
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

I'm guessing the json code is right. If not I think the structure I want to make there is clear.

So right now I want to extract the tasks with a foreach. So, everytime the loop runs it gets one value from the array task (example 1). After that I create a table with two colunms (id and task) so I want to print this information.

I tried to do as a starting point, but I got Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 26 Array.
This is what I tried:

```
<?php
// Encode the data.
$json = json_encode(
array(
    'error'=> 'false',
        'tasks' => array(
            1 => array(
                'id' => 4,
                'task' => 'Prueba'
            ),
            2 => array(
                'id' => 9,
                'task' => 'Psdasdrueba'
            ),
        ),
    )
);

// Define the errors.
$constants = get_defined_constants(true);
$json_errors = array();

$response = json_decode($json, true);
// Show the errors for different depths.
foreach (range(4, 3, -1) as $depth) {
echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you first encoding and after that decoding as JSON? Why are you trying to print the entire array? Why are you looping through a range?

Comment: I'm encoding that on json because it is actually a test. The real one is coming from an api with JSON code. I just tryed to print the array to look for an starting point and the continue developing. How should I remove the limit? @PeeHaa

Comment: ok that is an answer on one of the three questions I had.

Comment: *side note*, as `error` and `tasks` are at the same level in the array they really should be aligned - the way you've formatted it makes it look at first glance like tasks is the second level of the array.

Comment: So, should I do the for with the for with tasks? But then how can I get the id and the task? @Novocaine

Comment: What more do you need? @PeeHaa

Comment: ["Why are you trying to print the entire array? Why are you looping through a range?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815799/foreach-for-complex-array#comment44037901_27815799)

Comment: my comment was just a note on the formatting of the code you've written nothing to do with answering the question (hence only a comment). It just makes it easier to read if arrays are printed so that each level of the array is aligned correctly so that you can instantly tell at the start of a line that the next element is or is not at the same level as the previous element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always want to print the `$response` array. Loop through on the task array:

```
foreach ($response['tasks'] as $item) {
    echo "Id: " . $item['id']."<br />";
    echo "task: " . $item['task'] . "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined variable for `$id` and `$task` @lolka_bolka

Comment: Yes, my fault, I've edited my code. Please check now. Change `$id` to `$item['id'];`, and the task too.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
<?php
$json = json_encode(
array(
    'error'=> 'false',
        'tasks' => array(
            1 => array(
                'id' => 4,
                'task' => 'Prueba'
            ),
            2 => array(
                'id' => 9,
                'task' => 'Psdasdrueba'
            ),
        ),
    )
);
$response = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($response['tasks'] as $value)
{
echo "Id:".$value['id']."</br>";
echo "Task:".$value['task']."</br>";
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Id:4
Task:Prueba
Id:9
Task:Psdasdrueba
```